# How to get all window drive list in combobox or any other control

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

Hi i am working on homework task and want to populated all window drive list in combobox. and when I select the drive name from cambox then the folder/subfolder should be listed down in a Listbox.

I have populated the drive name in combobox here is my code:
[image: Screen shoot]

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
   Dim fso As FileSystemObject
   Dim d As Drive
   Dim dName As String
   Dim k As String
   Dim g As String
   Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.Filesystemobject")
       For Each d In fso.Drives
           k = d.DriveLetter
           dName = dName & "," & d
        Next d
            g = Mid(dName, 2, Len(dName))
            cboDrive.RowSource = g
        End Sub
```

Comment: Your combining late and early binding there - `Dim fso As FileSystemObject` and `Dim d As Drive` are early binding, while `Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.Filesystemobject")` is late binding.  Change `fso` & `d` to `Object` data types and remove the reference you've set to the `Microsoft Scripting Runtime`.

Answer (score 0):

This will print <strike>all</strike> network drives out to the immediate window, so you just have to change the `Debug.Print` bit to add it to your combobox.

```
Sub All_Drives()

    Dim oNtwrk As Object
    Dim oDrvs As Object
    Dim x As Long

    Set oNtwrk = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
    Set oDrvs = oNtwrk.EnumNetworkDrives

    For x = 0 To oDrvs.Count - 1 'Step 2 'Might need step 2... can't remember.
        Debug.Print oDrvs.Item(x)
    Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: actually I need window drive not network drive but this code is really useful I have change the code, now result is fine.
but I have another problem I need selected drive file in another listbox when i select any drive from combobox.

Comment: Could you edit your question with the code you have and screenshots of what you mean by  _selected drive file in another listbox when i select any drive from combobox_.

Comment: I have edited my question for your reference. please have look and guide me. also I have attached screenshot of my requirement.

Comment: you can see in attachment that I am able to get drive name in combobox, but now I want, when I select any drive from combobox the drive folder/subfulder shoul be show in listbox. please find the attached image.